# How to test DynamoDB aws in Jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, web-api-testing

Right now testing API which is hosted on amazon aws and it has dynamoDB. How do I check in Jmeter that DynamoDB table item count has increased than before sending my api requests?

Currently I am sending bulk requests to read json files, send them as body to same API endpoint and get their response. I want to check dynamoDB. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [DynamoDB JDBC Driver](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/community/) and drop it to JMeter Classpath
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
3. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) element and put your [DynamoDB JDBC URL](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-jdbc-dbv.rst) there. Other parameters like credentials, connection pool size, etc. can also be configured there
4. Add [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and put the query to get the current table item count. Save the result into a variable
5. You can use a [Response Assertion or JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions) to compare the item count with the expected value if needed.